# react native access to microphone android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I looked around react native api and couldn't find access to the microphone.  I want to access the phones microphone and then analyze the input data similar to what I'm doing with the web audio api below.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then((stream)=>{
      this.audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      this.analyser = this.audioCtx.createAnalyser();
      this.analyser.fftSize = 32;
      let source = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      source.connect(this.analyser);
      this.frequencyData = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
      this.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(this.frequencyData);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: There are some good libraries to access the microphone data: https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio and https://github.com/chadsmith/react-native-microphone-stream are the ones I personally know

Answer (score 0):

expo seems to be becoming the de facto react-native toolchain. It comes with a lot of useful development features and has a lot of extra modules on top of standard react-native modules. It appears they have an audio module https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/ although I have not tried.

https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-av

afaik you can install expo modules retroactively, but I prefer just bootstrapping a new project with the expo cli and copying over the code.

This is what I would try - [bootstrap a new project with the expo cli](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0) and see if the audio features you want are there.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)